# Сравнение объектов

Tags: java

Простой вопрос, но я запутался =) мне надо сделать сортировку объектов, я переопределил compareTo, и все работает, но мне надо, что бы можно было выбрать разные критерии сортировки этих объектов.

Comment: придумал вариант, но хотелось бы послушать еще...

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам это как-то поможет:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.Collections;    
import java.util.Comparator;    
import java.util.List;

public class Testing 
{

    public static void main(String[] argv) 
    {

        List<Ololo> list = new ArrayList<Ololo>();

        list.add(new Ololo("Chuck",71));
        list.add(new Ololo("Ivan", 27));
        list.add(new Ololo("Pavel",41));
        list.add(new Ololo("Dmitriy",36));

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getName()+": "+list.get(i).getAge());
        }    
        System.out.println("\n");
        Collections.sort(list,new Ololo.SortByName());

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getName()+": "+list.get(i).getAge());
        }  
        System.out.println("\n");
        Collections.sort(list,new Ololo.SortByAge());

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getName()+": "+list.get(i).getAge());
        }

    }    
}

class Ololo
{

    private String name = null;
    private int    age  = 0;
    public Ololo(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age  = age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public static class SortByName implements Comparator<Ololo>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Ololo t, Ololo t1) 
        {
            return (int) t.name.compareTo(t1.name);      
        }

    }

     public static class SortByAge implements Comparator<Ololo>
     {
        @Override
        public int compare(Ololo t, Ololo t1) 
        {
            return t.age - t1.age;
        }

     }

}
```

Comment: @gorets, Вариантов с компаратором, как Вы видите довольно много. 

Метод включения в класс флагов сортировки IMHO нельзя считать хорошим, т.к. Вам понадобиться менять его во всех элементах коллекции, если Вы решите пересортировать ее. 

Вынос флага в статический элемент класса на первый взгляд решает проблему, но возникнет проблема при параллельной сортировке разных коллекций (массивов) элементов данного класса.

Comment: 1) неправильные названия класов, должны быть: NameComparator, AgeComparator
2) они будут более гибкие если добавить boolean reverse параметр в конструктор класса. который позволит переключать режим сортировки: прямой/обратный

p.s. название класса Ololo само по себе "самодокументируемое" и "адекватное"

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите документацию. Например, вот один из методов для `java.util.Arrays`

```
sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Comment: ну тут понятно, я должен екстендить Comparator, на каждый тип сортировки и передавать в метод, вообще неплохо, но получается надо сделать много маленьких классов сортировки, я же придумал в элемент ставить флаг - тип сортировки, а в методе compareTo, проверять его и уже выбрать нужные критерии сравнения

Comment: Я обычно вызываю sort просто с новым текстом компаратора, что-то вроде:

     Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<MyClass>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(MyClass arg0, MyClass arg1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return arg0.age-arg1.age;
  }
  
 });